# Jmeter logs are missing

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

I am not able to see log messages in the logger view and not in jmeter.log. I am writing a simple jmeter groovy script [jsr223 listener].

```
org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager;
private static final Logger log = LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass();
log.info("your log message");
log.error("your error message");
println("something");
System.Out.Println("other thing");
```

Logs

```
2021-01-19 01:23:28,999 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-01-19 01:23:29,015 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-01-19 01:23:29,015 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2021-01-19 01:23:29,050 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2021-01-19 01:23:29,050 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2021-01-19 01:23:29,050 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-01-19 01:23:29,066 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-01-19 01:23:29,066 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-01-19 01:23:29,066 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-01-19 01:23:29,066 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2021-01-19 01:23:29,066 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2021-01-19 01:23:29,066 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2021-01-19 01:23:29,066 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2021-01-19 01:23:29,066 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Expecting to see log and error message atleast but none come through. Also , I tried jmeter 5.4.1 snapshot and same behavior. I am window OS / jmeter 5.4 . Can clue what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need the two first lines, `log` is a pre-defined variable for the JSR223 Test Elements, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.
2. The last line should look like `System.out.println("other thing");`
3. The last two lines print stuff not into the log file but to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))
4. You should see an error message, something like `unable to resolve class Logger`, if you don't see it - your listener is not being executed at all

[image]

Comment: I think my listener is not getting executed at all. Is dummy sampler is must . In my case it testplan > Thread Group > JSR233 Listener

Comment: Also when I add debug sampler only then it work but to run the test load debuf sampler is not advised

Comment: A listener won't be executed if you don't have any Samplers (same applies to [preprocessors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors)/[post processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)), either switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or add another Sampler of your choice.